# How to take file name from file in body, not from header when uploading file in Django Rest framework REST API?

Tags: python, django, rest

I have method which should upload file ( to be specific - image in JPG format) to some external storage (it does not matter where in this issue). Im sending Post request using Postman. I want that uploaded file to take name from file which I pass in my request body.
In Postman this file is passed in body as binary. Lets say this file is called dog.jpg.
However my request does not work If I won't add "Content-Disposition" header, and as value of this header I need to pass ": attachment; filename=dog2.jpg".
My file will be uploaded then as dog2.jpg, instead of dog.jpg. Also it is a little bit burdensome to have to change that name directly in headers everytime. Is there any way to avoid that header?

Beginning of my post method:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([FileUploadParser])
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def upload_image(request):
    print(request.FILES['file'])
    file = request.data.get('file')
```

For now

```
print(request.FILES['file'])
```

Would dog2.jpg

```
 file = request.data.get('file')
```

Would also return dog2.jpg

The rest of method I think is not important, as it is only logic to upload file to storage, which works perfectly fine.